# Using Api Event key insert data in dataextension

Tags: api, ampscript, journeybuilder

Hi all i am using amp script code with an journeybuider API EventDefinitionKey and client secret Code ,ClientID than i am try to insert Data in dataextension using below code please check my code and give me suggestion to acheieve this problem.

```
  %%[
    Var @body, @callstatus, @response, @accessToken, @resultOfParsing
    SET @auth="Bearer nmavun9GkFnWMA3WGF9M7gLM"
    Set @body = '{"ContactKey": "faheembics786@gmail.com", "EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-e0955f08-654f-f922-2896-12f76a6f8a5d","EstablishContactKey": true,"Data": { "FirstName":"Testw", 
   "Subscriberkey":"faheembics786@gmail.com","Email":"syed.faheem588+6685@gmail.com"}}'
    HTTPPost2("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/events", "application/json", @body, True, @callstatus, @response, 'Authorization', @auth)
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

The body is missing EstablishContactKey key-value pair and your contactKey value and subscriberkey value should be same.

Refer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm) for an example

Comment: thorugh api is worked everything but i need to using amp script code in landing page.I used same as you told code please check my above code.

Comment: if you have any modification in this problem please modify and send me code.